# Did the ISS not have a view of the James Webb launch? I presume so since I have not seen any videos

Tags: james-webb-telescope

It would have been nice if NASA could post a video or at least stills of the launch from orbit.

Comment: Good question! Since the core burns LH2/LOX which would be almost invisible, as soon as the SRBs dropped of it would probably disappear from view unless it were close, sunlit and against a dark background. I don't think it can leave a contrail in vacuum.

Comment: Even assuming the ISS was in a favorable position: Seeing a single rocket launch from 400++ km in daylight, showing at best a greyish-white exhaust plume against a greyish-white overcast cloudbase? Not very likely, and **very** little to see if they did locate it.

Comment: ISS-based photography and videography of launches is not unknown.